# Long multiply, 8 bits at a time

Tags: code-golf, math

You are given a 16-bit machine and told to implement multiplication of arbitrary-sized integers.  Your registers can only hold 16-bit numbers, and the biggest multiply instruction takes two 8-bit inputs and generates a 16-bit result.

Your program must take as input two arbitrary-sized positive numbers and output their product.  Each input number is encoded on its own line as a little-endian byte array where each byte is a 2-digit hex number.  The output must be similarly formatted.  Perhaps best explained with an example:

**input**

```
1f 4a 07
63 a3
```

**output**

```
fd 66 03 a7 04
```

which encodes the multiplication 477727*41827=19981887229.

You can assume that the last (most significant) byte of each input number is nonzero, and the last chunk of the number you output must be nonzero.  Both input numbers will be at most 100 bytes long.

Smallest code wins.

Remember, the biggest multiply you are allowed to use is 1 byte * 1 byte, and no integer types bigger than 2 bytes!

Comment: This is crucial for languages, that have no default 8-bit type, like Haskell.

Comment: What about addition? Can we pretend to have a ready-made arbitrary-size addition function? If not, what *can* we add?

Comment: @Timwi: You can do anything you'd like 16 bits at a time.  Adds, shifts, whatever.  Any larger operation you need to synthesize yourself.

Comment: +1 for correct byte order

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Perl, 137 characters

```
($x,$y)=<>;while($x=~s/.. *//s){$e=hex$&;$i=0;$s=$r[$i]+=$e*hex,$r[$i]&=255,$r[++$i]+=$s>>8 for$y=~/.. */gs;$y="00$y"}printf'%02x 'x@r,@r
```

### Caveats

- Sometimes prints an extra `00` byte at the end of the result. Of course the result is still correct even with that extra byte.
- Prints an extra space after the last hex byte in the result.

### Explanation

The explanation is going to be a bit long, but I think most people here will find it interesting.

First of all, when I was 10 years old, I was taught the following little trick. You can multiply any two positive numbers with this. I will describe this using the example of 13 × 47. You start by writing the first number, 13, and *dividing* it by 2 (round down each time) until you reach 1:

```
13
 6
 3
 1
```

Now, next to the 13 you write the other number, 47, and keep *multiplying* it by 2 the same number of times:

```
13     47
 6     94
 3    188
 1    376
```

Now you cross out all the lines where the number on the left is *even*. In this case, this is only the 6. (I can’t do strike-through in code, so I’ll just remove it.) Finally, you add all the remaining numbers on the right:

```
13     47
 3    188
 1    376
     ----
      611
```

And this is the right answer. 13 × 47 = 611.

Now, since you are all computer geeks, you will have realised that what we’re actually doing in the left and right columns is `x >> 1` and `y << 1`, respectively. Furthermore, we add the `y` only if `x & 1 == 1`. This translates directly into an algorithm, which I’ll write here in pseudocode:

```
input x, y
result = 0
while x > 0:
    if x & 1 == 1:
        result = result + y
    x = x >> 1
    y = y << 1
print result
```

We can re-write the `if` to use a multiplication, and then we can easily change this so that it works on a byte-by-byte basis instead of bit-by-bit:

```
input x, y
result = 0
while x > 0:
    result = result + (y * (x & 255))
    x = x >> 8
    y = y << 8
print result
```

This still contains a multiplication with `y`, which is arbitrary-size, so we need to change that into a loop too. We’ll do that in Perl.

Now translate everything to Perl:

- `$x` and `$y` are the inputs in hex format, so they have the *least* significant byte *first*.
- Thus, instead of `x >> 8` I do `$x =~ s/.. *//s`. I need the space+star because the last byte might not have a space on it (could use space+`?` too). This automatically puts the removed byte (`x & 255`) into `$&`.
- `y << 8` is simply `$y = "00$y"`.
- The `result` is actually a numerical array, `@r`. At the end, each element of `@r` contains one byte of the answer, but halfway through the calculation it may contain more than one byte. I’ll prove to you below that each value is never more than *two* bytes (16 bits) and that the result is always one byte at the end.

So here is the Perl code unravelled and commented:

```
# Input x and y
($x, $y) = <>;

# Do the equivalent of $& = x & 255, x = x >> 8
while ($x =~ s/.. *//s)
{
    # Let e = x & 255
    $e = hex $&;

    # For every byte in y... (notice this sets $_ to each byte)
    $i = 0;
    for ($y =~ /.. */gs)
    {
        # Do the multiplication of two single-byte values.
        $s = $r[$i] += $e*hex,
        # Truncate the value in $r[$i] to one byte. The rest of it is still in $s
        $r[$i] &= 255,
        # Move to the next array item and add the carry there.
        $r[++$i] += $s >> 8
    }

    # Do the equivalent of y = y << 8
    $y = "00$y"
}

# Output the result in hex format.
printf '%02x ' x @r, @r
```

Now for the proof that this always outputs *bytes*, and that the calculation never generates values greater than *two* bytes. I’ll prove this by induction over the `while` loop:

- The empty `@r` at the beginning clearly has no values greater than 0xFF in it (because it has no values in it at all). This concludes the base case.
- Now, given that `@r` contains only single bytes at the beginning of each `while` iteration:

  - The `for` loop explicitly `&=`s all values in the result array with 255 *except the last one*, so we only need to look at that last one.
  - We know that we always remove only one byte from `$x` and `$y`:

    - Therefore, `$e*hex` is a multiplication of two single-byte values, which means it’s in the range `0 — 0xFE01`.
    - By the inductive hypothesis, `$r[$i]` is one byte; therefore, `$s = $r[$i] += $e*hex` is in the range `0 — 0xFF00`.
    - Therefore, `$s >> 8` is always one byte.
  - `$y` grows an extra `00` in each iteration of the `while` loop:

    - Therefore, in every iteration of the `while` loop, the inner `for` loop runs for one more iteration than it did in the previous `while` iteration.
    - Therefore, the `$r[++$i] += $s >> 8` in the last iteration of the `for` loop always adds `$s >> 8` to `0`, and we already established that `$s >> 8` is always one byte.
  - Therefore, the last value stored in `@r` at the end of the `for` loop is also a single byte.

This concludes a wonderful and exciting challenge. Thanks a lot for posting it!

Answer (score 4):

**C Solution**

This solution does no input validation.  It's also only lightly tested.  Speed was not really a consideration.  Malloc's memory, and isn't particularly clever about how much it grabs.  Guaranteed to be enough, and more than necessary.

m() accepts a string, expects two newlines in the string, one after each number.  Expects only numbers, lowercase characters, spaces, and newlines.  Expects hex digits to always be a pair.

No multiply operation is ever used (knowingly).  Shifting is performed on 8-bit variables.  One 16-bit addition is performed.  No 32-bit data types.

Shrunk by hand, and only mildly.  **edit:** more obfuscation, fewer chars :D  Compiles with warnings with gcc.

Characters: 675

```
typedef unsigned char u8;
#define x calloc
#define f for
#define l p++
#define E *p>57?*p-87:*p-48
#define g(a) --i;--a;continue
void m(u8*d){short n=0,m=0,a,b,i,k,s;u8*t,*q,*r,*p=d,o;f(;*p!=10;n++,l){}l;f(;*p
!=10;m++,l){}t=x(n,1);q=x(m,1);r=x(n,1);p=d;a=n;i=0;f(;*p!=10;i++,l){if(*p==32){
g(a);}t[i]=E;t[i]<<=4;l;t[i]|=E;}a/=2;b=m;i=0;l;f(;*p!=10;i++,l){if(*p==32){g(b)
;}q[i]=E;q[i]<<=4;l;q[i]|=E;}b/=2;f(k=0;k<8*b;k++){if(q[0]&1){o=0;f(i=0;i<n;i++)
{s=o+t[i]+r[i];o=s>>8;r[i]=s&255;}}f(i=n;i;i--){o=t[i-1]>>7&1;t[i-1]*=2;if(i!=n)
t[i]|=o;}f(i=0;i<m;i++){o=q[i]&1;q[i]/=2;if(i)q[i-1]|=(o<<7);}}k=(r[a+b-1]==0)?a
+b-1:b+a;f(i=0;i<k;i++){printf("%02x ",r[i]);}putchar(10);}
```

You can test with this:

```
int main(void){
  m("1f 4a 07\n63 a3\n");
  m("ff ff ff ff\nff ff ff ff\n");
  m("10 20 30 40\n50 60 70\n");
  m("01 02 03 04 05 06\n01 01 01\n");
  m("00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01\n00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
$ ./long 
fd 66 03 a7 04 
01 00 00 00 fe ff ff ff 
00 05 10 22 34 2d 1c 
01 03 06 09 0c 0f 0b 06 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02
```

Answer (score 4):

## OCaml + Batteries, 362 characters

A standard O(n*m) schoolboy multiplication algorithm. Note that in order to meet the challenge requirements, the operations are done on the bytes of strings, which in OCaml are (conveniently, in this case) mutable. Note also that the accumulator `s` never overflows 16 bits, since 2(2^8 - 1) + (2^8 - 1)^2 = (2^8 - 1)(2^8 + 1) = 2^16 - 1.

```
let(@)=List.map
let m a b=Char.(String.(let e s=of_list(((^)"0x"|-to_int|-chr)@nsplit s" ")in
let a,b=e a,e b in let m,n=length a,length b in let c=make(m+n)'\000'in
iteri(fun i d->let s,x=ref 0,code d in iteri(fun j e->let y=code e in
s:=!s+code c.[i+j]+x*y;c.[i+j]<-chr(!s mod
256);s:=!s/256)b;c.[i+n]<-chr!s)a;join" "((code|-Printf.sprintf"%02x")@to_list c)))
```

For example,

```
# m "1f 4a 07" "63 a3" ;;
- : string = "fd 66 03 a7 04"

# m "ff ff ff ff" "ff ff ff ff" ;;
- : string = "01 00 00 00 fe ff ff ff"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 160 bytes

```javascript
x=>y=>x.map((t,i)=>y.map(u=>(f=i=>(c=s[i]>>8)&&f(i++,s[i]=c+~~s[i],s[i-1]%=256))(i,s[i]=~~s[i++]+`0x${t}`*`0x${u}`)),s=[])&&s.map(t=>(t<16?0:'')+t.toString(16))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BbsIwEER/JQeKd3GIkkJThFhz4wc4oki2AkGu0jjCCwpC8OvBSS@9jObNSDM/5mZ8ebEtzxt3PPU76jtSd1Jd8mtaAI4tBh7hSgoqskFL8gdbKLXC6bQCK2U8MJXy9RrMQPOs@KDPrxwR7F87dlIWUqfd5MFPPRvN9akRY0@HIoz58YjDBW@yfJuuhUDJCbs9X2xzhizs9aVrvKtPSe3OsAORVdHSROm3SHxbW9aRRhD5IjKLfwn2bw)

Lot newer language than that time though

Answer (score 0):

## 8086 DOS .COM file, 134 bytes

It works now!

What better language to do this in than 16-bit assembly?

```
00000000: b9 c8 00 89 cd 31 c0 f3 50 89 e7 e8 5d 00 92 aa  .....1..P...]...
00000010: 74 f9 29 e7 87 fb 89 e6 8d 3a e8 4e 00 9c 56 57  t.)......:.N..VW
00000020: 89 d9 ac f6 e2 03 05 ab 83 15 00 4f e2 f4 5f 5e  ...........O.._^
00000030: 47 9d 74 e6 80 39 00 74 01 4b 01 df 01 e5 29 ef  G.t..9.t.K....).
00000040: 89 ee ac 88 c3 b1 04 d2 e8 e8 10 00 93 24 0f e8  .............$..
00000050: 0a 00 b0 20 e8 0d 00 4f 75 e8 cd 20 3c 09 76 02  ... ...Ou.. <.v.
00000060: 04 27 04 30 b4 02 88 c2 cd 21 c3 b2 00 b4 01 cd  .'.0.....!......
00000070: 21 2c 30 72 0e 3c 0a 72 02 2c 27 b1 04 d2 e2 00  !,0r.<.r.,'.....
00000080: c2 eb ea 3c f0 c3                                ...<..
```

My first, and likely last 16-bit 8086 program.

Assembly (NASM with C comments because of syntax highlighting):

```c
        // sed -i -e 's#//#;#g' dosmult.asm
        // nasm -f bin dosmult.asm -o dosmult.com

        // The default, but never harmed anyone.
        [bits 16]
        // 8086 code only! If I use 386 instructions or any of that,
        // I would ruin the challenge.
        [cpu 8086]
        // COM files start at 100h.
        org 100h

        section .text

start:
        // Create a 400 byte buffer on the stack.
        // 200 will be reserved for the input, and 200 for the output.
        mov     cx, 200
        // Save 200 in BP for later, it will be useful.
        mov     bp, cx
        // Push 0 200 times making a 400 byte zeroed buffer on the stack
        xor     ax, ax
        rep     push ax

        mov     di, sp
        // Read the first line of hex digits.
.getline_loop:
        call    gethex
        // Swap DL to AL and store with STOSB
        xchg    dx, ax
        stosb
        // Loop if it was a space
        jz      .getline_loop

        // Get length
        sub     di, sp
        // Store length in BX
        xchg    di, bx
        // Save the pointer to input in SI
        mov     si, sp
        // Load the pointer to output in DI (SI + 200)
        lea     di, [si + bp]

        // Begin multiplication, grade school byte by byte
        // Instead of creating a third buffer, we process the data
        // as the user inputs it.
.loop:
        call    gethex
        // Save flags from gethex so we know when to stop
        pushfw
        // Save SI and DI
        push    si
        push    di
        // Loop counter
        mov     cx, bx
.mult_loop:
        // Load next byte from first input
        lodsb
        // Multiply by the input byte
        mul     dl
        // 16-bit add to [DI]
        // We actually add to AX, then do STOSW.
        add     ax, [di]
        stosw
        // Add the carry bit.
        adc     word [di], 0
        // Decrement DI after STOSW incremented it by 2 to iterate
        // on each byte.
        dec     di
        // while (--cx)
        loop    .mult_loop
.mult_loop_end:
        // Restore DI and SI
        pop     di
        pop     si
        // Increment output pointer
        inc     di
        // Restore flags from gethex
        popfw
        // Jump if we got a space.
        jz      .loop

.loop_end:
        // Was there a trailing zero?
        cmp     byte[di + bx], 0
        jz      .nodec
.dec:
        // If so, decrement the count.
        dec     bx
.nodec:
        // Calculate the length with ugly pointer arithmetic.
        // I feel there is a better way to do this.
        add     di, bx // ptr += len
        add     sp, bp // sp += 200 (sp = output)
        sub     di, sp // ptr -= output
        // Store output array in SI.
        mov     si, sp
        // Print each byte in hex
.print_loop:
        // Load byte
        lodsb
        // puthex(AL >> 4)
        mov     bl, al
        mov     cl, 4
        shr     al, cl
        call    puthex
        // puthex(AL & 0Fh)
        xchg    ax, bx
        and     al, 0Fh
        call    puthex
        // putc(' ')
        mov     al, ' '
        call    putc
        // Loop for every byte from DI.
        dec     di
        jnz     .print_loop
.print_loop_end:
        // exit, not bothering to clean anything up. :P
        int     20h

        // Prints hex digit in AL.
        // Must be <= 0fh
puthex:
        cmp     al, 9
        jbe     .no_hexa
.hexa:
        add     al, 'a' - '9' - 1
.no_hexa:
        add     al, '0'
        // Fallthrough

        // Prints AL to stdout.
putc:
        mov     ah, 2h
        mov     dl, al
        int     21h
        ret

        // Reads a hex byte.
        // Returns in DL.
        // Sets whether it ended in a space in the Z flag.
gethex:
        mov     dl, 0
.start:
        // Read char into AL
        mov     ah, 1h
        int     21h
        // Subtract ASCII '0'
        sub     al, '0'
        // If we hit a space or newline, they will trigger the 'below'
        // condition
        jb      .ret
        // Was AL '0'-'9'? If not, correct it to 'a'-'f'.
        cmp     al, 10
        jb      .no_hexa
.hexa:
        // Correct AL
        sub     al, 'a' - '9' - 1
.no_hexa:
        // DL = (DL << 4) + AL
        // 8086 doesn't have shift by immediate.
        mov     cl, 4
        shl     dl, cl
        // Add to BL
        add     dl, al
        // Loop
        jmp     .start
.ret:
        // Check if AL before the subtraction was a space.
        cmp     al, ' ' - '0'
        ret
```

Naturally, being a 16-bit instruction set, I am only doing 8-bit and 16-bit arithmetic (and I don't use the 16-bit `mul`).

Beats the Perl answer by 3 bytes. Granted, this is binary machine code and that is source code, so I guess this isn't that much to get excited about. However, 8086 lacks a lot of the features Perl has (about 1/3 of it is just I/O and hex conversion ).

I am sure there are multiple optimizations possible here. A lot of my knowledge is from writing 32-bit and 64-bit code, so I am not fully knowledgeable in the 16-bit tricks.

Input is from stdin, in space separated lowercase hex, each ending in a new line. It is not line buffered, so no typos allowed! :P

Output is printed to stdout.